# Trouble with output from abstract classes in java

Tags: java, abstract-class

I am trying to print values from methods in an abstract class. There is a switch statement that calls abstract methods and a statement that prints items in the array. I tried case 1 (Add new circle) and then case 6(Display shapes.

[image: Output image]

Could be problem with specifiers or with call statements made in case 6?

```
package lab8;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    // DATA
    Shape[] shapes = new Shape[10];
    int nextIDNumber = 1;
    boolean exit = false;
    int selection;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int id;
    double x, y;
    double base = 0, height = 0, width = 0, radius = 0, scaleFactor;
    boolean found = false;

    // ALGORITHM
    // loop until user exits
    do
    {
        // display menu
        System.out.println("1 Add a new circle");
        System.out.println("2 Add a new rectangle");
        System.out.println("3 Add a new right triangle");
        System.out.println("4 Delete a shape");
        System.out.println("5 Delete all shape");
        System.out.println("6 Display all shapes");
        System.out.println("7 Move a shape");
        System.out.println("8 Enter a scale factor");
        System.out.println("9 Scale all shapes");
        System.out.println("10 Exit program");

        // get user choice
        selection = input.nextInt();
        while (selection < 1 || selection > 10)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter valid choice");
            selection = input.nextInt();
        }

        // switch on selection
        switch(selection)
        {
        case 1:
            // ADD NEW CIRCLE
            System.out.println("Enter radius for your circle: ");
            radius = input.nextDouble();
            // get size from user (one variable)

            // get location from user (two variables)
            System.out.println("Enter x location for your circle: ");
            x = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter y location for your circle: ");
            y = input.nextDouble();
            // set found to false
            found = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
                if (shapes[i] == null) {
                    shapes[i] = new Circle (nextIDNumber++, x, y, radius);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!found) {
                System.out.println("Array is full. ERROR");
            }
            break;

            // loop through array
                // if this is not a valid object
                    // create new Circle object and assign to current array element

                    // set found to true

                    // break out of loop

            // if not found, give error message

            // break out of switch statement

        case 2:
            // ADD NEW RECTANGLE
            // get size from user (two variables)
            System.out.println("Enter height of rectagle: ");
            height = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter width of rectagle: ");
            width = input.nextDouble();
            // get location from user (two variables)
            System.out.println("Enter x location for your rectangle: ");
            x = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter y location for your rectangle: ");
            y = input.nextDouble();
            // set found to false
            found = false;
            
            for (int i = 0; i< shapes.length;i++) {
                if(shapes[i] != null) {
                    shapes[i] = new Rectangle(nextIDNumber++, x,y, height, width);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!found) {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
            break;
            
        case 3:
            // ADD NEW RIGHT TRIANGLE
            // get size from user (two variables)
            System.out.println("Enter the base: ");
            base = input.nextDouble();
            while (base <= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid number, please enter positive number");
                base = input.nextDouble();
            }

            System.out.println("Enter the height");
            height = input.nextDouble();
            while (height <= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid number, please enter positive number");
                height = input.nextDouble();
            }

            // get location from user (two variables)
            System.out.println("Enter X location");
            x = input.nextDouble();
            while (x < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid number, please enter positive number or zero");
                x = input.nextDouble();
            }

            System.out.println("Enter Y location");
            y = input.nextInt();
            while (y < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid number, please enter positive number or zero");
                y = input.nextDouble();
            }

            // set found to false
            found = false;

            // loop through array
            for (int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++)
            {
                // if this is not a valid object
                if (shapes[i] == null)
                {
                    // create new RightTriangle object and assign to current array element
                    shapes[i] = new RightTriangle(nextIDNumber++, x, y, base, height);
                    // set found to true
                    found = true;

                    // break out of loop
                    break;
                }
            }

            // if not found, give error message
            if (!found)
            {
                System.out.println("No more room");
            }

            // break out of switch statement
            break;

        case 4:
            // DELETE ONE SHAPE
            // get id number to delete
            System.out.println("Enter ID of shape to be deleted: ");
            id = input.nextInt();
            found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i< shapes.length; i++) {
                if (id == shapes[i].getID() && shapes[i] != null) {
                    shapes[i] = null;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                System.out.println("Shape not found.");
            }
            break;

        case 5:
            // DELETE ALL SHAPES
            System.out.println("Are you sure you want to delete all shapes? 1] YES 2] NO : ");
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            if(choice == 1) {
                for (int i= 0; i<shapes.length; i++) {
                    if(shapes[i]!=null) {
                        shapes[i] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            // DISPLAY ALL SHAPES
            // print header
            System.out.println("Here are our shapes");
            System.out.printf("%10s %10s %10s %10s %10s\n", "ID", "X", "Y", "AREA", "PERIMETER");
            for (int i = 0; i<shapes.length;i++) {
                if (shapes[i] != null) {
                    System.out.printf("%10d %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10f\n", shapes[i].getID(),shapes[i].getxLoc(),shapes[i].getyLoc(),shapes[i].getArea(),
                    shapes[i].getPerimiter() );
                    
                    
                    }
            }
            break;
            

        case 7:
            // MOVE A SHAPE
            System.out.println("Enter the ID of shape:");
            id = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter X location of shape:");
            x = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter Y location of shape:");
            y = input.nextDouble();
            found = false;
            for(int i =0; i<shapes.length;i++) {
                if(id == shapes[i].getID() && shapes[i] != null) {
                    shapes[i].setxLoc(x);
                    shapes[i].setxLoc(y);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                System.out.println("Not found.");
            }
            break;
            
        case 8:
            // ENTER A SCALE FACTOR
            System.out.println("Enter scale factor: ");
            scaleFactor = input.nextDouble();
            Shape.setScaleFactor(scaleFactor);
            break;
            
            // get scale factor

            // call SetScaleFactor to set the new scale factor

            // break out of switch statement

        case 9:
            // SCALE ALL SHAPES
            for(int i =0;i<shapes.length;i++) {
                if (shapes[i] != null) {
                    shapes[i].scaleShape();
                }
            }
            
            // loop through array
                // if this is a valid object
                    // call ScaleShape

            // break out of switch statement
            break;

        case 10:
            System.out.println("Do you want to exit? \n1] YES\n2] NO");
            int user = input.nextInt();
            if(user == 1) {
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
                exit = true;
            }
            
            break;
            // EXIT PROGRAM
            // confirm user wants to exit
                // set variable to break out of loop

            // break out of switch statement
        }

    } while (!exit);

}
```

}

```
abstract class Shape
{
    // declare static variable
    public static double scaleFactor;

    // declare instance variables
    private int id;
    private double xLoc;
    private double yLoc;
    
    // one constructor
    public Shape(int i, double x, double y) {
        i = id;
        x = xLoc;
        y = yLoc;
        }

    // get/set methods
    public static double getScaleFactor() {
        return scaleFactor;
    }
    public static void setScaleFactor(double scaleFactor) {
        if (scaleFactor > 0) {
            Shape.scaleFactor = scaleFactor;
        }
    }
    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setID(int i) {
        if (i > 0 ) {
            i = id;
        }
    }
    public double getxLoc() {
        return xLoc;
    }
    public void setxLoc(double x) {
        x = xLoc;
    }
    public double getyLoc() {
        return yLoc;
    }
    public void setyLoc(double y) {
        y = yLoc;
    }

    // abstract methods
    public abstract double getArea();
    public abstract double getPerimiter();
    public abstract void scaleShape();
    
}

class Circle extends Shape
{
    // declare instance variable
    private double radius;
    
    public Circle (int i, double x, double y, double r){
        super(i, x, y);
        r = radius;
    }

    // get/set methods
    public double getRadius()
    {
        return radius;
    }
    public void setRadius(double r)
    {
        if (r > 0.0)
        {
            radius = r;
        }
    }

    // override abstract methods
    // GetPerimeter method
    public  double getPerimiter() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }

    // GetArea method
    public double getArea() {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }


    // ScaleShape method
    public void scaleShape() {
        radius = radius * scaleFactor;
        setRadius(radius);
        
    }
    }
```

Comment: You need to learn to think logically about what your code is doing when something goes wrong.  What was wrong in this case?  Where there were supposed to be interesting numbers, there were only zeros.  So the you should as yourself "Where do those values come from?".  Then you use a visual debugger to look at the locations where those values are being accessed, and see if they are zeros or not.  If they are zeros, then you'd look back from there by following the logic for where those numbers come from, the input side of the code.  This is all I did, and it's pretty basic.  Use your debugger!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your assignments wrong in your constructors, so the values associated with your shapes are all zero.  You need to switch them around.  This constructor:

```
// one constructor
public Shape(int i, double x, double y) {
    i = id;
    x = xLoc;
    y = yLoc;
}
```

should be this:

```
public Shape(int i, double x, double y) {
    id = i;
    xLoc = x;
    yLoc = y;
}
```

and this:

```
    public Circle (int i, double x, double y, double r){
    super(i, x, y);
    r = radius;
}
```

should be this:

```
public Circle (int i, double x, double y, double r){
    super(i, x, y);
    radius = r;
}
```